# Why I can't upload sqlite file to the OneDrive?

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, onedrive

I am developing an Windows Runtime Universal Application.

I need to upload the database I'm using in my application to the user's OneDrive?

But `FileNotFound` exception occurs. But I know the path is correct.

Since I refer the sqlite file, it shows the exception. If I refer txt file, Uploading process goes smoothly.

```
var authClient = new LiveAuthClient();
var authResult = await authClient.LoginAsync(new string[] { "wl.skydrive", "wl.skydrive_update" });
if (authResult.Session != null)
{
    var liveConnectClient = new LiveConnectClient(authResult.Session);
    var FileToUpload = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("text.sqlite");//exception occurs here        
    var FileToUpload = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("text.txt");//no exception for txt files

    var folderData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    folderData.Add("name", "Folder") 
    LiveOperationResult operationResult = await liveConnectClient.PostAsync("me/skydrive", folderData);

    LiveUploadOperation uploadOperation = await liveConnectClient.CreateBackgroundUploadAsync(folderId, "filename", FileToUpload, OverwriteOption.Overwrite);
    LiveOperationResult uploadResult = await uploadOperation.StartAsync();
    HandleUploadResult(uploadResult);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use a background transfer task to move a file that large and to handle the occasion when the user gets a call during transfer. Background tasks are the key.

> http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Transfer-Sample-d7833f61/sourcecode?fileId=52027&pathId=1495533284

Sort of like this.

```
BackgroundUploader uploader = new BackgroundUploader(); 
UploadOperation upload = uploader.CreateUpload(uri, file); 
await HandleUploadAsync(upload, true);
```

But before you even do that, you need to assume that the user will manipulate the database. As a result, you should copy the database file before you start the upload. Again, code:

```
var sourceFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var sourceFile = await sourceFolder.CreateFileAsync("database", 
    Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
var targetFolder = await sourceFolder.CreateFolderAsync("~", 
    Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
var targetFile = await targetFolder.CreateFileAsync(sourceFile.Name,
    Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
await sourceFile.MoveAndReplaceAsync(targetFile);
```

This is not only a good idea, I have a feeling it will correct the problems you are having. Remember you can always query and ask if a transfer is done (do you aren't doing two).

Best of luck!